# VBA Private Object Out Scope in Same Form

Tags: vba, excel, scope

I'm trying to learn VBA by writing a simple game but I'm running into issues with the scope of my objects.  When the main form is opened I want a new instance of the gameSession class to be initialized. Then, when the user clicks a button, I want to use that instance. But even though my object is declared at the top of the form it appears that it isn't included in the scope of the forms procedures. How do I get each procedure to recognize the same instance of the object?

```
Option Explicit

Private gameSession As clsGame

Private Sub btnWalk_Click()
   Call frmZombieRun.gameSession.Walk
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Set frmZombieRun.gameSession = New clsGame
End Sub
```

If I put a watch on the variables I see that each instance of gameSession has a different context (frmZombieRun, frmZombieRun.btnWalk_Click, and frmZombieRun.UserForm_Initialize) and therefore is out of context when I reach the btnWalk routine.

I get a compile error: Method or data member not found.

Comment: Does `clsGame` not have a `Walk` public method? Exactly what code gets highlighted when you get the compile error? FWIW compile error and "when I put a watch on variables" can't be in the same sentence: if the code can be debugged, then it compiles. If it doesn't compile, it can't be debugged.

Comment: Also FWIW all these assumptions you're making about the context/scope are erroneous and distract from the actual problem.

Comment: That was a stupid oversight on my part, the walk method was private. Thanks for the help! (And for pointing out my issues with how I was calling my form).

Comment: For the record, editing the question like you did makes my answer look like it's making up code...

Comment: I wasn't sure how would be best to update it. In the future would it be better to have to seperate code blocks (the original and the edited) or to explain what changes I had made in text? Or is there a different standard to how that's best done?

Comment: Since SO is a Q&A site and not a debugging service (millions of people google their problems and land here, every day), ideally a Q&A should remain consistent at all times. The question you asked originally was a legitimate bug that could bite anyone, and its solution is below. The updated issue about method not being found would be a separate thing that *could* be its own question (though of little value), but anyone reading the comments would pick up the solution to that secondary problem. Hence, I've rolled back the last edit. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's *not* in scope.

The `gameSession` field is `Private`, which means it's only accessible to *this instance* of the form.

If you made it `Public`, your code would compile and probably work, until you changed how the form is shown, from this:

```
frmZombieRun.Show ' off the default instance
```

to this:

```
With New frmZombieRun
    .Show ' not off the default instance
End With
```

Referring to the default instance in a form's code-behind *will* cause problems, sooner or later. Read more about it [here](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) (disclaimer: I wrote that article).

Use `Me` instead, to refer to *the current instance*:

```
[Call] Me.gameSession.Walk 'note: Call is redundant/deprecated/obsolete
```

But that breaks encapsulation, that field *should* probably be `Private` like you have it, i.e. not accessible from the form's public interface. So, drop the qualifier and access your private field directly:

```
[Call] gameSession.Walk
```

You'll also need to do the same for the initialization handler:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Set gameSession = New clsGame
End Sub
```

Consider dropping the `frm` and `cls` pseudo-Hungarian prefixes, they're not buying you anything.

Comment: Changing it to public and/or dropping the qualifier/using Me makes no apparent difference. I still receive the out of context error.

Comment: @JackyD I assumed that code was in the code-behind of `frmZombieRun`. Is it? Also exactly what is "out of context" error? This answer covers the question you asked, with the information you provided. If something's missing, please edit your question to include it.

Comment: My apologies, I'm referring to the compile error: method or data member not found. And yes, this is the code-behind for frmZombieRun.

Comment: And that's the issue right there. The walk method was Private which I completely overlooked.